# Groupby() in pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with the following columns:

> Country, Year, Population, Suicide case, Country GDP

Problem: I Want to calculate (Suicide case / Population )*100 for each country

My Approach :

```
import pandas as pd
fileName = pd.read_csv("File Path")
pd.groupby("Country")
```

How should I extend my code for the calculation above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have with an example. May be it could be better, but this should work for you.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Country":["France", "UK", "France", "UK"], 
                   "Population":[1, 2, 3, 4],
                   "Suicide case":[5, 3, 6, 2]})
df_grouped = df.groupby("Country").sum()
(df_grouped["Suicide case"]/df_grouped["Population"])*100
```

Answer (score 2):

Also a more concise one is:

```
df.groupby('Country').apply(lambda x: x['Suicide case'].sum()/
                               float(x['Population'].sum())*100)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly then you can try below code to get your desired result:

```
fileName = fileName.groupby(['Year','Country']).sum()
fileName['New_var'] = (fileName['Suicide case']/ fileName['Population'])*100
```

you also need to the year in the group otherwise year-wise will also get aggregate.